# Where can I find a list of Apple preferences/plist files & what they're used for?

Tags: preferences, plist

Does anyone know of a resource that lists the Preferences files/plists (pertinent to OS X and Apple applications, not third-party apps) found in `~/Library/Preferences` (and the other locations too, but that would be a start) and what they're used for?

I've been looking around and can't find anything.  The closest I found was [this chart compiled by appleexaminer.com](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkBdGlxJhW-ydDlxVUxWUVU0dXVzMzUxRzh2b2ZzaFE&hl=en_US#gid=0) — but that only covers a few items, and the obvious ones at that.

Comment: make a backup and try to change stuff in there, you will find out soon enough...

Comment: No, that doesn't help me at all. I would like a resource that lists every file in ~/Preferences & what it does. Your suggestion doesn't provide that.

Comment: I really doubt you'll find a complete list.  Generally each application you run will record its settings in a file in ~/Preferences -- and since there are a huge number of apps ([AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/) currently lists 10,764 in the Mac App Store), nobody's going to bother trying to compile a complete list.

Comment: Ah—I should have been clearer. I'm just interested in Apple's Preferences. Thanks for forcing me to clarify!

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy to figure out which files in `~/Library/Preferences` are used by Apple applications and which app.

All the Apple ones start `com.apple` and then almost all continue with the name of the application or part of the system that they are a preference for - some examples `com.apple.ScreenSharing.plist` or `com.apple.TextEdit.plist`

With the less "specific" ones once you know more about how the back end of the System and Finder hang together you start to realise what they are, for example `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` is the one that defines your personal URL and file type handlers as that is done by LaunchServices.

Mac sysadmins tend to slowly get a list of the more important ones as we use them to push preferences out to our managed Macs. If all else fails I use [InstallEase](http://www.absolute.com/en/products/installease), the free utility from Absolute, to snapshot a Mac then change a preference and do another snapshot to see what changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Pref Setter](http://www.nightproductions.net) appears to do exactly that.

Comment: OK, how is that? On the website, it's described thusly: "Pref Setter is an application used to edit plist (Property LIST) files, geared towards viewing / editing Mac OS X's preference files. Very useful for setting those “hidden” preference settings that aren't available directly in an application."


So how does that tell me what each Preference/plist file DOES? I can't see that Pref Setter does that at all.

Comment: First, open it. Then click on the little blue window with the I in it, Get Info. Haven't seen anything else that will do that, and it's very cool.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can examine by yourself like

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" \
    /Users/kevit/Library/Address\ Book\ Plug-Ins/SkypeABSMS.bundle/Contents/Info.plist
```

List of keys is described in Apple's Developer documentation on [Property List Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html), Cocoa Apps part.

Unfortunately, lot of developers ignore recommendations